# SQL distinct latest post

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

I know the very very basics of MySQL but I can't seem to figure out the following problem I have.

I try to display conversations between two users in an overview,  where the last message between these two users will be shown.

So this:

```
Message           Date           User
Lipsum            10-10-2015     Bob
Lorem             11-10-2015     John
Dolor             11-10-2015     Bob
```

Will become this:

```
Dolor             from Bob
Lorem             from John
```

The message sql table looks like this:

```
MESSAGEID         DATE           FROM_USERID          TO_USERID
```

Comment: I try to show only the last message per user

Comment: Similar question was posted here :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/612231/how-can-i-select-rows-with-maxcolumn-value-distinct-by-another-column-in-sql?rq=1

Comment: My problem is not solved, I didn't formulate my question properly, so I've uploaded a new one (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28152702/sql-conversation-chat-like-output?noredirect=1#comment44676761_28152702)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question properly, you need following query:

```
select t1.MESSAGEID,t1.MESSAGE, concat('from ',USERNAME) FROM_USER
from tblMsg t1 inner join 
    (select MAX(MESSAGEID) MESSAGEID,FROM_USERID
     from tblMsg
     group by FROM_USERID) t2 on t1.MESSAGEID=t2.MESSAGEID
    inner join tblUser u on t1.FROM_USERID=u.USERID
```

**[DEMO SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/83e9ce/4)**

Comment: my bad that was a column named FROM_smth